# C++ odd-even array, infinite answer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, infinite-loop

This program supposed to read the number of elements and a list, and split the array for even and odd numbers, and display the number of zeros in original array.
I posted a question before for the first problem I had with this program and the answers were really helpful since this is an assignment. But now I have another problem which is every time I run the program it gave me `0 'z.` and it does not stop until I close the window. I think the problem is with the count function but I was not able to diagnose the problem by myself.  I added:

```
cout<< odd_num<< "     " << even_num;
```

after I called count function to find out what is the problem and it gave me a really big number so whatever the error is, it is coming from this function.

So please help me! I'm sure for most of you this is very basic but I just started to learn this and really appreciate it if you can help me.

*Edit:* I edited this code and the only problem is an extra zero as output; look at the example output at the end.

Here is the code:

```
int count(const int list[],  int size, int & odd , int & even)

{
    int zero(0); 
    for (int i(0); i<size ; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == 0)
        {
            zero++; 
        }
        if (list[i]% 2 ==0 & list[i]!=0)
        {
            even++; 
        }
        else if (list[i]% 2 ==1 & list[i]!=0)
        {
            odd++; 
        }
    }
    return  zero;

}


void split(const int list[], int size, int list_even[], int even_num, int list_odd[], int odd_num )
{
    int j(0); 
    int k(0); 

    for (int i(0); i<size; i++)
    {
        if(list[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            list_even[j]= list[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if(list[i]%2 != 0)
        {
            list_odd[k]= list[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (j != even_num || k != odd_num) 
    {
        cerr << "Error.";
    }


}

// function to print an  array
void print_list(int array[], int length)
{
    for (int a=0; a<length; a++)
    {
        cout <<array[a]<<" ";
    }
}
```

And here is the sample answer:

```
Enter number of elements: 3
Enter list:
2
30
0
Error.Even elements:
2 30 0 0
Odd elements:

There were 1 zeros in the list
```

Another sample is:

```
Enter number of elements: 3
Enter list:
2
1
5
Error.Even elements:
2 2752708
Odd elements:
1 5 2762032 2752708
There were 0 zeros in the list
```

Comment: You call `count()` twice, which I'd normally say is 'odd', but maybe I should say is 'an even number of times' in this context.  This means that your variables referenced by `even` and `odd` get incremented to twice the correct value. You could help yourself by printing out the result values for `count()` somewhere, either in the function or afterwards.

Comment: `int zero_num(0);` and `for (int i(0);` - this is a very unusual application of allowed syntax. The most obvious downside is that if you decide to change `list = new int[size];` to it's own variable and maintain consistency, it has to become `int* list(new int[size]);` instead of just adding `int*` at the beginning to produce `int* list = new int[size];`. But the biggest draw back is that ... nobody else does this. Especially not the `for` loop usage. I'd strongly discourage you from teaching yourself this practice, unless you are convinced you can counter it's negative effects in interviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not initialize your variables try:

```
   int zero_num(0); // number of zeros
   int even_num(0);
   int odd_num(0);
```

Try printing them out before you start using them (before this fix) and see what they are set too. :)

---

Fix to your count function:

```
// function to copy odd and even number to seperate arrays
void split(const int list[], int size, int list_even[], int even_num, int list_odd[], int odd_num )
{
    int j(0);
    int k(0);

    for (int i(0); i<size; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == 0)
        {   // zeros are not considered even in the count function
            // so they should not be added here.
            continue;
        }
        else if(list[i]%2 == 0)
        {
            list_even[j]= list[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if(list[i]%2 != 0)
        {
            list_odd[k]= list[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    // test that we have found the right number of even and odd numbers.
    if (j != even_num || k != odd_num)
    {
        cerr << "Error.";
    }
```

}

---

And to make sure that multiple calls to the count function does not mess up your numbers make this change:

```
//function to count the odd and even numbers and th enumber od zeros
int count(const int list[],  int size, int & odd , int & even)

{
    // reset the even and odd counts before we start.
    odd=0;
    even=0;

    int zero(0); // variable to count zeros
    for (int i(0); i<size ; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == 0)
        {
            zero++;
        }
        else if (list[i]% 2 == 0 )
        {
            even++;
        }
        else if (list[i]% 2 == 1 )
        {
            odd++;
        }
    }
    return  zero;
}
```

---

Sample output:

```
Enter number of elements: 5
Enter list:
1
2
5
0
0
Even elements: 2

Odd elements: 1
5

There were 2 zeros in the list
```

Another sample output with zeros in begining and middle:

```
Enter number of elements: 5
Enter list:
0
2
0
1
7
Even elements: 2

Odd elements: 1
7

There were 2 zeros in the list
```

Comment: it worked! one problem: there is two extra 0 s at the end of out put. please take a look at edited code and sample answer. again, Thank u so much

Comment: I will load it in VC++ up and debug.. standby :).

Comment: Your split function has an issue that is why you are printing error. You are testing that you found the correct number of even/odd number in the loop instead of outside the loop. :) looking at your print now.

Comment: Because you called your count method twice and you passed the counts by reference they were twice the count by the time you reached the rest of your logic:).

Comment: worked! perfect. so i changed the firs count call and done. the problem was I was thinking if I want to assign the result of a function to another variable I have to call it first and then again call it after variable. interesting

Comment: stii it prints error before  even elements! and it is not working if user enters more than one zero!

Comment: Did you use my version? There was also the issue that it was counting zeros as even numbers. so the count at the end would not be correct for even numbers. Also it would potential crash since it would put more things in even then the size of the array.

Comment: yes and I think I understood what happened this time. just to make sure:
I did not set the variables to 0 in function, so every time I the function it will mess with the result.  also I should checck for 0 in split function to make sure I'm not counting it as an even or odd number. and that was why I had this "error" before even. Thank you so much

Comment: Awesome! You are on your way to becoming an expert :)

Comment: Can you take a look at my new problem :)

Answer (score 3):

In if condition you are using `&` which is bit-wise operator instead of `&&` which is `Logical AND`.

See:

```
if (list[i]% 2 ==0 & list[i]!=0)
    {
        even++;
    }
```

use `&&` instead and see if it works, else drop me a message.

Comment: You were correct.. I did away with them entirely in the end :).

Comment: No problem @Rob, we programmers do mistakes in hurry. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Improvement] How about to write your count function like this,

```
int count(const int list[],  int size, int & odd , int & even)
{
    int zero(0);
    for (int i(0); i<size; ++i)
    {
        if (list[i]==0)
        {
            ++zero;
        }
        else
        {
            if (list[i]%2==0) ++even;
            else ++odd;
        }
    }
    return zero;
}
```